# Finding Min/Max Of $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3x-12y+20$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3x-12y+20$$

$\nabla f(x,y)= (3x^2-3,3y^2-12)=(0,0)$

So  $3x^2=3\iff x=\pm 1$ $3y^2=12\iff y=\pm 2$

$\begin{pmatrix} 
f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\
f_{yx} & f_{yy} 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
6x & 0 \\
0 & 6y 
\end{pmatrix}$

So at $(1,2): D>0 \text{ and }f_{xx}>0$ so it is a minimum point

$(1,-2): D<0  \text{ and }f_{xx}>0$ so it is a saddle point

$(-1,2): D<0  \text{ and }f_{xx}<0$ so it is a saddle point

$(-1,-2): D>0  \text{ and }f_{xx}<0$ so it is a maximum point

Do wy need check all the combinations of $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$ like I did?

Comment: I guess you mean local minima/maxima? Or do you want to find and classify all critical points? It's very easy to see that $f$ does not have global maxima or minima.

Comment: I need to classify all the points, so I need to add that there is no global max/min?

Comment: yes there is no global max/min

Answer (score 1):

Your work seems fine for me. If $(x,y)$ is a (local) maximum or minimum of a differentiable function defined in an open set, then $\nabla f(x,y) = (0,0)$. So the critical points $(1,2)$, $(-1,2)$, $(1,-2)$ and $(-1,-2)$ you found are candidates for (local) maxima or minima.

If $f$ is twice differentiable, then you can use the Hessian to classify the critical points previously found - which you did pretty much correctly. But since this analysis is only local, you only have that $(1,2)$ is a local minimum and $(-1,-2)$ is a local maximum.

There are no global minimum or global maximum, since $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} f(x,0) = \pm \infty$.